# SqlBulkCopy speed test

Tags: vb.net

I am importing some data from excel file into the sql database using vb.net. I am using SqlBulkCopy to do this. I tested the speed of this method and discovered that when specify BatchSize=300 is 2 seconds slower when i do not specify BatchSize at all. Is this possible? I thougt it will be faster whith specified batch size because of less communication with database.

```
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlworksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim newCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
    Dim OldCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo

    xlapp = New Excel.Application

    OldCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    newCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(xlapp.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAppLanguageID.msoLanguageIDUI))
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture

    xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("E:\KREZA\petrovac.xls")
    xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim tabela As DataTable
    tabela = New DataTable

    For i As Integer = 1 To 4
        tabela.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
    Next

    For i As Integer = 1 To xlworksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        tabela.Rows.Add(CInt(xlworksheet.Cells(i, 4).value.ToString), xlworksheet.Cells(i, 2).value.ToString, CInt(xlworksheet.Cells(i, 9).value.ToString), CDbl(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(xlworksheet.Cells(i, 5).value.ToString, Len(xlworksheet.Cells(i, 5).value.ToString) - 3)))

    Next

    xlworkbook.Close()
    xlapp.Quit()

    cnparfimerija.Open()
    Using copy As New SqlBulkCopy(cnparfimerija)
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1)
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2)
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 3)
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 4)


        copy.DestinationTableName = "ArtikliPetrovac"
        copy.BatchSize = 300
        copy.WriteToServer(tabela)
    End Using
    cnparfimerija.Close()

    MessageBox.Show("Uspesno")
```

Comment: These things are always a balancing act.  Changing the batch size changes more than one thing about the process.  Some things may make it more efficient and some may make it less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's according to your Db and number of rows i guess i also faced similar issue but i had like 1Lakh + rows each to time to import to database so i sent it an optimal batch size of 4000. Increasing and decreasing  than this caused system to slow down the copying process.